# I cannot push large model or artifacts in my mlflow

Tags: mlflow

First of all, thank you to everyone who helps.
I have a one question about pushing my artifacts and model.

Here is my Error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14HIn.png)

I think there is a limit to what sendall can do on a socket. If there is any way to improve this, please let me know.

All timeout settings have been increased.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyEFx.png)

I made the above settings, but the results did not change.

For reference, Models and Artifacts are approximately 10G.